# Getting query error: Out of stack space due to deeply nested query expression during query resolution in google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

While running a query I am getting this error. However let's say if I rerun it so it might run in a normal way. I am executing this inside a VM and there is now pattern as to when it runs and when it doesn't. What can be the permanent solution to this problem to ensure it runs everytime.

I tried rerunning it if I get an excpetion inside VM upto certain steps. But I think that's not a proper solution to ensure it run every time as it is a critical production job